# AudioKit SynthOne crashes after returning from background

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

We're using a "skinless" version of AK SynthOne in our app (i.e., just the engine, with a collection of presets), and seeing a consistent crash when returning from background. In order to spare the user's battery when the sequence is *not* playing, if the user goes to background, we call `AudioKit.stop()`. This allows the CPU usage to fall to zero (happy customers!), but on returning we see a consistent crash when SynthOne tries to handle its first note:

```
void S1NoteState::startNoteHelper(int noteNumber, int velocity, float frequency) {
    oscmorph1->freq = frequency;    // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS here!
    oscmorph2->freq = frequency;
    subOsc->freq = frequency;
    fmOsc->freq = frequency;

    ...
```

The backtrace:

```
* thread #13, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100fc5d78 Spliqs`S1NoteState::startNoteHelper(this=0x0000000108345500, noteNumber=56, velocity=54, frequency=207.652328) at S1NoteState.mm:105:21
    frame #1: 0x0000000100fd6764 Spliqs`S1DSPKernel::turnOnKey(this=0x00000001088a3790, noteNumber=56, velocity=54, frequency=207.652328) at S1DSPKernel+toggleKeys.mm:85:14
    frame #2: 0x0000000100fcabd0 Spliqs`S1DSPKernel::startNote(this=0x00000001088a3790, noteNumber=56, velocity=54, frequency=207.652328) at S1DSPKernel+startStopNotes.mm:45:9
    frame #3: 0x0000000100fc1298 Spliqs`::-[S1AudioUnit startNote:velocity:frequency:](self=0x00000001088a3600, _cmd="startNote:velocity:frequency:", note='8', velocity='6', frequency=207.652328) at S1AudioUnit.mm:98:13
    frame #4: 0x00000001014cf86c Spliqs`AKSynthOne.play(noteNumber=56, velocity=54, frequency=207.65233610331066, channel=0, self=0x0000000280de4a00) at AKSynthOne.swift:223:21
    frame #5: 0x00000001016dbda4 Spliqs`AudioKit.AKPolyphonicNode.play(noteNumber: Swift.UInt8, velocity: Swift.UInt8, channel: Swift.UInt8) -> () + 328
    frame #6: 0x000000010135a120 Spliqs`Conductor.handleMIDI(data1=146, data2=56, data3=54, self=0x000000010820efe0) at Conductor.swift:392:23
    frame #7: 0x00000001013597a4 Spliqs`Conductor.handle(event=AudioKit.AKMIDIEvent @ 0x000000016f488ba0, self=0x000000010820efe0) at Conductor.swift:374:26
    frame #8: 0x0000000101358de4 Spliqs`closure #1 in Conductor.setUpMIDIHandler(packetList=0x000000016f489e98, _0=nil, self=0x000000010820efe0) at Conductor.swift:326:30
    frame #9: 0x0000000101157f48 Spliqs`thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned UnsafePointer<MIDIPacketList>, @unowned UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> () at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #10: 0x00000001d42467b8 CoreMIDI`LocalMIDIReceiverList::HandleMIDIIn(unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, MIDIPacketList const*) + 164
    frame #11: 0x00000001d4246618 CoreMIDI`MIDIProcess::RunMIDIInThread() + 132
    frame #12: 0x00000001d425d1e8 CoreMIDI`XThread::RunHelper(void*) + 28
    frame #13: 0x00000001d4262624 CoreMIDI`CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 92
    frame #14: 0x00000001c3eef908 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 132
    frame #15: 0x00000001c3eef864 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 48
    frame #16: 0x00000001c3ef7dcc libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 4
```

We've tried everything from just starting AudioKit, through to completely re-initializing SynthOne, but it's always the same.

We've been stuck on this one for a while, so any thoughts greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Actually, I'm afraid I have to resuscitate this question. Although the `.pause()` approach in my answer below worked for going to/from background we also have a use-case where we move to offline render mode to export audio. That process definitely *does* require us to stop the engine (in order to switch modes), and we're getting the same SynthOne-related crash when handling the first event after `AudioKit.start()`. Does anybody understand why we'd hit an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when returning? I'm guessing that memory has been incorrectly reallocated/reclaimed(?) somehow, but how can I prevent it?
I suppose, more broadly, the question would be: how do I safely start/stop the AudioKit engine when using SynthOne.

Answer (score 2):

Erm... yikes... how about `.stopEngine()` and `.startEngine()`...? an rtfm moment, for sure.

For anyone who might face a similar problem, these use `AudioKit.engine.pause()` and `AudioKit.engine.start()`, as opposed to using `stop()`.

Comment: Just to finalize this, the start/stop problem was ultimately solved by upgrading everything to Swift 5, latest versions of AudioKit and SynthOne..